# Why the command system() does not work in R?

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I am running an .Rmd script in **R 4.2.0**.
This script executes several **system()** commands.

However, some of these commands return 127 in the console window in **Rstudio 2022.02.3 Build 492** (I think that this output refers to the **error 127**), while other commands are simply not executed (mkdir or /din/mv for instance).

I am running R and Rstudio under **Windows 10 Pro**.

I read the suggestion that in Windows the system() command works better in this style for instance:

```
system("cmd.exe", input = "cd ..")
```

But also this simple command does not work. The output is like that:

```
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\User\me\Documents>cd ..

C:\User\me>[1] 0
```

However, if I type:

```
system("cmd.exe", input = "cd ..")
```

The directory is not changed:

```
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\User\me\Documents>pwd

C:/User/me/Documents
```

As a consequence the .Rmd script cannot create subdirectories and save new files generated from the data elaboration.

I hope someone can find the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to change folders using system commands? You can change e.g. the working directory, or when saving files refer to the parent directory.

Comment: I don't understand exactly, but when I add "wsl" (windows subsystem linux) in front of my system() commands, it seems to magically work sometimes.

Comment: Yes @Axeman I tried to change the working directory in Rstudio through: Session ---> Set Working Directory ---> Chose Directory.  
Apparently the outcome is fine:                                                                                       `> setwd("D:/Bioinformatics/baerhunter/baerhunter_paper/project")`
`> system("pwd")`
`/d/Bioinformatics/baerhunter/baerhunter_paper/project [1] 0`

However, the outcome is like that:
`> system("mkdir output/")`  
still creates the folder in the path `C:\Users\Me\Documents`